# Has importance for something

Tags: sentence-structure

Is the sentence below correct?
 It has no importance for me what do people think about me.

Comment: There shouldn't be a _do_. Embedded question complements do not undergo _Do_-Support. Other than that, it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome.

I agree with the comment.  The word "do" in the original sentence is unnecessary and should be removed. Then it sounds alright.  The two examples below only need to be changed slightly to sound more natural:

> It is **of no importance** *to me* what people think about me.

**or**

> It is **not important** *to me* what people think about me.

Using either of these two changes (first change bolded and second change in italics) makes the original sentences sound better.

Comment: "It is of no importance what people think of me."